# Term for language that abstracts program location?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, history

What is the technical term that describes a programming language that abstracts (or at least largely abstracts) the machine location of programs? I’m thinking here specifically of the evolution of handheld calculator programming languages, from early (and some late) models where each instruction exists in a single linear space (e.g., HP RPN calculators before the 41 series), to (some) later models such as the 41 series and the 42S, where each program exists in its own space.

Is there a formal term for this difference?

(Note that I’m thinking here exclusively of cases like the examples given, where the languages used are otherwise the same — here RPN keystep programming — and not of more radical changes in language and system architecture — e.g., RPL.)

Comment: What are you talking about? Can you give a *concrete* example?

Comment: What does it mean to "abstract the machine location of programs"?  Please [edit] your question to define/explain what you mean by that.  What do you mean by "its own space"?  We need to understand what you're asking before we have a chance of being able to answer it.

Comment: There has been the notion of [position-independent code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). I don't remember any language (class) named for it.